# Unable to save macro enabled excel

Tags: python, excel

We are trying to automate one process. Part of the this process is where we populate some fields in the excel. This excel is macro (vba macro) enabled and has buttons which when clicked macro validates the populated data. We can't access source code of these macros as it is password enabled ( and also due to compliance issue). We are getting issue when we are trying to save this excel to some other location as these macro button are not visible in the newly saved excel. Can you please advice.

Comment: Please create a [reprex]. How are you saving this file? What library/libraries are you using?